# Reducing "Quad Roots"

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Active member of Stack Overflow who is brushing up his mathematics skills after several years of inactivity.  I appreciate the help in advance!

My question is pretty basic.  I have having a hard time remembering how to reduce down complex roots.  I have no problem with datastructures/algorithms/etc, but have gained a few holes in the purely mathematical part of my mind.

Example that I am struggling with:

$$f(x) = \sqrt[4]{4-x^4}$$

This is a simple "find the domain" problem.  Logically, I know exactly how to deduce the domain.  That is incredibly simple.  It is the "breaking down the quad root into a workable presentation" that I am unfortunately stumped on.  Thanks again for the help!

Comment: That's not a cube root

Comment: But I'm not seeing any cube roots in your equation!  Cheerio!

Comment: A cube root is a third root, not a fourth root.

Comment: Whoops!  Quad root.  Making an edit :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fourth roots, which you have here, can only (in the reals) be taken of positive numbers or zero.  You need $4-x^4 \ge 0$, which gives $|x| \le \sqrt[4]4=\sqrt2$

Comment: So it can be assumed, then, that $\sqrt[x]{x}=\sqrt{x/2}$?

Comment: @AndrewRhyne No; here $\sqrt[4]{2^2}=\sqrt{2}$ is used. Similarly $\sqrt[4]{9}=\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: so $\sqrt[4]{x}=\sqrt{\sqrt{x}}$ ?

Comment: Ah gotcha.  make complete sense when it is broken down that way.  This part of my mind is very weak apparently ;)

Comment: You have $\sqrt[n]a=a^{1/n}$ so $\sqrt[4]4=4^{1/4}=(2^2)^{1/4}=2^{2\cdot (1/4)}=2^{1/2}=\sqrt 2$

Answer (score 4):

The domain of $f$ is precisely where $\sqrt[4]{4-x^4}$ is defined, i.e. when

$$4-x^4 \ge 0 \Rightarrow 4 \ge x^4 \Rightarrow |x| \le \sqrt{2}.$$

So, the domain is $\left[-\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2} \right]$.